# typescript class member function grouping

Tags: typescript, properties, namespaces

I would like to basically alias class member functions so that they can appear under a property of a class but the functions can still access the normal class variables basically this is what I would like to do

testClass:

```
class Test{
    var1 = 0;
    groupA.myFunc(){
        var1 = var1 - 5;
        return var1;
    }

    groupB.myFunc(){
        var1++;
        return var1;
    }
}
```

how it would work:

```
let testClass = Test();
testClass.groupA.myFunc();
testClass.groupB.myFunc();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
class Test {
  var1 = 0;

  groupA = {
    myFunc: () => {
      this.var1 = this.var1 - 5;
      return this.var1;
    }
  }

  groupB = {
    myFunc: () => {
      this.var1++;
      return this.var1;
    }
  }
}
```

The arrow functions mean that the `this` refers to the `Test` instance, not the `groupA` or `groupB` objects.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0BuYBOAjNALzQAMA3JtAOZ4D2ArgA4CCJa1WAtgJ4BijAHbAAXNAAUAShIA+TlkXQkACwCWEAHS5CHVRu34iAWmgBWKkqx54SRniHL1WnQUuKAvtS-U6TZgBCHBhKfIIi4tJyClb6LkYA1AnuSjZ2Dk4GrinQXlhePujA9ELIyogopELwAO5wFdJUSBWafiysmmHCwI3ozcitDCwBnQLdjUA)